# Avoid subquery and 2nd group by?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm stuck with something which is seemingly easy but I can't figure it out.

**Table1** contains CountryID, CompanyID, PersonID, ItemID.
**Table2** contains several AttributeIDs which refer to a specific CountryID and Company ID.

The goal is to query how many unique CompanyIDs with AttributeID=1 exist within each CountryID.

Is there are a better way to achieve this than the solution below?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0d53/2/0

```
CREATE TABLE table1 
(
 CountryID int, 
 CompanyID int, 
 PersonID int,
 ItemID int);

INSERT INTO table1 (CountryID, CompanyID, PersonID, ItemID)
VALUES (1,1,4,9),(1,1,6,3),(1,2,8,4),(1,2,4,1),(1,2,7,4),(2,1,1,2),(2,1,2,1),(2,2,5,1),(2,2,8,3),(2,2,10,2);

CREATE TABLE table2 
(
 CountryID int, 
 CompanyID int, 
 AttributeID int
);

INSERT INTO table2 (CountryID, CompanyID, AttributeID)
VALUES (1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,2,2),(1,2,5),(2,1,1),(2,2,1),(2,2,3),(2,2,5);
```

The solution I have so far:

```
select t3.CountryID, count(*) as Count_of_Companies_with_AttributeID1 from
(select t1.CountryID, t1.CompanyID from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
on t1.CountryID=t2.CountryID and t1.CompanyID=t2.CompanyID
where t2.AttributeID=1
group by t1.CountryID, t1.CompanyID) as t3
group by t3.CountryID
```

Thank you for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this as an aggregation query with a `join`:

```
select t1.CountryId, count(distinct t2.CompanyId)
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.CountryID = t2.CountryID and t1.CompanyID = t2.CompanyID
where t2.AttributeId = 1
group by t1.CountryId;
```